# MacBook Air cycle count history

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I know how to check the cycle count on a Mac but does anybody know how to check the history of when each cycle count increased along with the date?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this information is logged. The cycle count is stored in the battery itself, and I'd be surprised if it contained this level of detail data.

All Apple needs to know is: "is it above/below 80% original capacity, or passed 1000 cycles?" If those conditions are met, then they will replace it.

The rate, or curve, of cycle usage is largely irrelevant.

Applications like Coconut Battery allow the user to create a history, by storing time-stamped 'snapshots' of the battery's condition; but the fact that such an app requires the user to do that, suggests that there's no such feature built-in.